# Can't seem to receive callback data in telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

For context, I'm using the pyTelegramBotAPI to build a flight tracker. I feel like the following code is right but for some reason when I click on any inline button I just get a clock icon on the button and no response back. This is how I'm passing my information through and this function itself works fine and runs every time:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"], func=lambda msg: is_user(msg.chat.id))
async def start_is_user(m):
    cid = m.chat.id
    if next_step_handler(cid) == 'menu' or next_step_handler(cid) == 0: #function to define my next step
        currUser = db.users.find_one(str(cid)) #using mongodb here to get the currUser
        userStep[cid] = 'menu' #dict to keep track of the current step of the currUser
        await bot.send_chat_action(cid, "typing")
        await bot.send_message(
            cid,
            (f"Hello {currUser['fname']}, I'm a bot programmed" 
        " to find you the best tickets home. To get started click on the following "),
            reply_markup=inline_generator(menu_options)
        )
```

This is how my inline_generator function is producing the keyboard. I've included the menu_options for context:

```py
menu_options = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'New Flight'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Track Flights'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Settings'},
]

#fairly simple code to produce a grid of keys with width 2
def inline_generator(options):
    temp = []
    curr = 0
    keyboard = []
    while curr < len(options):
        while len(temp) < 2 and curr<len(options): #looks redundant but len(temp) can be under 2 and have curr>len(options) which I don't want
            temp.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=options[curr]['name'], callback_data=options[curr]['id']))
            curr += 1
        keyboard.append(temp)
        temp = []
    return types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=keyboard)
```

Again the problem here is that every time I click on something in my inline keyboard, I don't seem to be receiving any callback data because I don't enter my callback query handler which looks something like this:

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
async def menu_callback_query(call):
    cid = call.message.chat.id
    await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    await bot.send_chat_action(cid, "typing")
    print(f"reached menu_callback_query and current call is {call.data}") #this print statement is never reached
    if call.data == 0:
        userStep[cid] = "menu"
    if call.data == 1 :
        await bot.edit_message_text(
            text=responses["ticket_type"],
            chat_id=cid,
            reply_markup=inline_generator(ticket_options),
        )
        userStep[cid] = "ticket_type"
    if call.data == 2:
        await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, responses["no_flights"])
    if call.data == 3:
        await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, responses["not_user"])
```

I attempted to use a message handler instead of callback query handler but that didn't work. I also changed the func in the callback query handler to None instead of (func=lambda call: True) and that didn't change anything.

Any assistance in understanding how to debug this to my console would also be greatly appreciated! This is my first time coding for a school project so I'm not sure what a best practice for catching these sorts of bugs might be